# Ember-data RecordArray isLoaded Status

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Can any one explain to me why a RecordArray status `isLoaded` is set to true before even a success method on an ajax call is called.

From ember-data source code

```
  findAll: function(store, type, since) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type);

    this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "GET", {
      data: this.sinceQuery(since),
      success: function(json) {
          debugger;
        Ember.run(this, function(){
          this.didFindAll(store, type, json);
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

Defined in a view

```
handler: function() {        
    var content, controller = this.get('controller');
    if(controller.get('content.isLoaded')) {
    }
}.observes('controller.content.isLoaded')
```

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be an ongoing bug with `isLoaded` properties being set prematurely on collections. Here is [the relevant issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/587) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using an old version of Ember: I found that if you wrap whatever you're doing with `Ember.run.next`, content is *actually loaded* by then.

Not the prettiest solution but it worked for me in Ember v1.0.