# how to really find out only once if Ember finishes its ajax request and DS.RecordArray is completely filled

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ajax-request

I have probably tried a gazillion ways and nothing is efficient. My last attempt - which works a little well but with an ugly tradeoff was this:

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find({}).then(function(response) {
      return response;
    });
  }
});
```

the problem with this - which **I'd love to know** is its making a synchronous call. My HTML/DOM won't finish loading until this returns.

Another thing **I'd love to know** is if I omit the empty object {} from the find - the promise function actually gets called immediately. I promise!

Now other methods I've tried are the following which all have flaws:

- observing content.lastObject.isLoaded on a controller
- implementing arrayContentDidChange from Ember.ArrayController - obviously this gets triggerd multiple times as the array is getting filled.
  -

Answer (score 1):

> I have probably tried a gazillion ways and nothing is efficient.

I don't know if you tried hooking into the `afterModel` function of a route which is an addition added not very long ago and available in rc6:

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(users, transition) {
    console.log(users.get('length'));
  }
});
```

See [here](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) for more info on the hooks `beforeModel` and `afterModel`.

I've also put togheter a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/33/edit) to play around.

Hope it helps.

Comment: don't think its available now - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html and unfortunately your jsbin isn't working. I also tried the afterModel hook on my app, wasn't called :(

Comment: @David, it is available (http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js) but only not documented on the website. what is not working on the provided jsbin? I can see length 3 in the console, you don't?

Comment: @David, oh crap, this must be a jsbin issue :/ the html tab is basically empty... I'll fix that give me just a moment.

Comment: @David, ok fixed the jsbin, have a look now.

Comment: thanks so much for being helpful. Also may I add, I'm using rc3 - but i replaced it with rc6 (rc3 doesn't have afterModel), but when i did, look at the sequence of execution on my app - http://d.pr/i/nGXQ If you look at it, all the hooks were called. BUT, all of them were called before the ajax request actually finishes. My UsersRoute model method only has this method code -  App.User.find(). I feel like you get different result with fixtures than an actual ajax call.

Comment: same link right? http://jsbin.com/odosoy/30/edit ? or maybe you have a differet one now - because your the same link still have the HTML basically empty.

Comment: @David, no it's updated in my answer and should point to http://jsbin.com/odosoy/33/edit, and here a version with latency set to three seconds http://jsbin.com/odosoy/34/edit which waits for the afterModel to be called, very strange that you don't get the correct result...

Comment: thanks man, i'll study your code tomorrow but definitely thanks for the help. just a little bit late for me at this moment.

Answer (score -1):

You can read about it here https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735
There is a question like yours [Ember-data RecordArray isLoaded Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272279/ember-data-recordarray-isloaded-status).
Also you can try to observe `isUpdating` to be false instead of `isLoading`

Comment: Sorry i have to down vote your answer. I hope you understand that I  have gone through a lot of different ways and right now what I need is a solution.